# DebugKit not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

On my CakePHP 3.1.7 DebugKit 3.0.0-beta2 is installed.

debug is set to true, pdo_sqlite is installed

If I load a page on the browser /tmp/debug_kit.sqlite is created

No error message at /logs, no error message in apache log, no errors on Firebug.

But still I can not see the debugkit panel. What am I missing?

Comment: Somehow I had a DebugKit folder in /plugins. I removed it, removed and reinstalled debugkit and now it is ok.

Comment: I have DebugKit in vendors, but it still doesn't show in my views... any ideas?